# Django - gunicorn on App Engine. Error: 'No Module Named my_project'

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I'm trying to upload my Django(v2.0) application to Google App Engine, but Gunicorn(v19.7.1) can't find my app. When I deploy my app using `gcloud app deploy` I get error

> 'No Module Named AppFlex'

Full screenshot of the error and app.yaml config is below.

[image]

The contents of the **wsgi.py** are:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "AppFlex.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Additionally, I can run the app locally using:

```
gunicorn AppFlex.wsgi --workers 16
```

Another screenshot where I can run the app using gunicorn locally :

[image]

Comment: does solarissmoke answer help or not?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, forgot to mark it correct. I had to re-install everything with lower-case letters. Otherwise, there's an error running using run server command, but works find for gunicorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your top level module (`AppFlex`) is camel-cased, and for some reason App Engine expects only lower case module names.

If you change your module name to `appflex` and update the corresponding configuration in `app.yaml` and everywhere else that your top level module is referenced (e.g., in `wsgi.pi`) it should work.

I am not too sure why App Engine is doing that, but it is [convention for modules to be lower case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), and I'd strongly suggest you follow that convention.