# Python 3 Django on App Engine Standard: App Fails to Start

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Django application on Google App Engine in the Standard Python37 Environment. I've had a version of it running fine in the Flexible environment, but I'm creating a staging version that I want to run in the Standard env.

When I deploy and visit the app I get a 500 error. Looking in the logs I can see some messages about exceptions in worker processes. I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

This is the stack trace from the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
>   worker.init_process()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process
>   super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
>   self.load_wsgi()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
>   self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
>   self.callable = self.load()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
>   return self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
>   return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
>   **import**(module)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

I haven't modified `my_site/wsgi.py` since Django created it for me, here it is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_site.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
env: standard

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: project:us-west1:sql-instance

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: staticfiles/
- url: .*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: my_site.wsgi.application

env_variables:
  # vars
```

This matches pretty close with the `app.yaml` in: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine.
I've also tried changing `script` to `auto` as shown here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref, but still get the same error.

I've looked at this question: [Django - gunicorn on App Engine. Error: 'No Module Named my_project'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836949/django-gunicorn-on-app-engine-error-no-module-named-my-project), and `my_site` does have an underscore in it, but isn't camelCased.

I'm not sure what the source of this error is. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to add `entrypoint` to your app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 my_site.wsgi

...(remaining parts of your app.yaml)
```

Reference: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

Comment: That was it. I believe it was because I included gunicorn in requirements.txt but did not explicitly set the entrypoint

Answer (score 0):

You can also deploy it without entrypoint but your app object needs to be located  in `main.py` file in root directory.

Check example description of such deployment [here](https://rogulski.it/blog/gae-standard-py37-django/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.