# Issue running Python37 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-3.7

I know this question has been asked in some facet or another, but I have gone through readings as shown here and I am still not seeing where my issue is as I am still unable to publish my Django 2.1.1 app in the Python37 environment in Google App Engine:

[Python 3 Django on App Engine Standard: App Fails to Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416588/python-3-django-on-app-engine-standard-app-fails-to-start)

Overall what I am attempting to do is publish a simple app engine app using:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

My application works locally but when I publish, it goes through without issue, but I get the annoying:

> > 500 Server Error message

When I look at the logs in Google I get the same error as many others have gotten:

> > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

**here is my relevant directory structure**

project_portal

- project_portal

  - init.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
- main.py
- app.yaml
- requirements.txt

**my app.yaml file**

```
    runtime: python37
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project_portal.wsgi
    env: standard


    handlers:
    - url: .*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: project_portal.wsgi.application
```

**my project_portal/wsgi.py file**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_portal.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**from main.py in project root**

```
from project_portal.wsgi import application
```

**from requirements.txt**

```
django == 2.1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an `entrypoint` defined, it will try to start from a file called `main.py`.  Create one, at the same level as `app.yaml`with some simple logic in it:

```
from project_portal.wsgi import application
```

**Edit:**

Since you have an `entrypoint` defined, it seems that is the issue. So, make sure you have gunicorn in your 'requirements.txt':

`gunicorn==19.9.0`

**This did not help:**

<del>Try changing</del>

<del>`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project_portal.wsgi`</del>

<del>to</del>

<del>`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project_portal.wsgi:application`</del>

Comment: Seems like more needs to be done. I have done what you suggested and now I am still getting the 500 error but I cannot seem to view the logs to see what the issue is.

Comment: I assume some other things are handled, like having a directory called `staticfiles`, and having django in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes it was and I just tried taking out the static listing in my app.yaml because I do not have any static files yet, I am just trying to ensure I understand how to deploy to GAE. Give me a second and I'll update with my requirements.txt contents and the new app.yaml

Comment: I am still running into issues. If I keep main.py, it runs but I get no error notification that "main" cannot be found. If I remove main.py and alter the entrypoint as we have discussed I get the same "cannot find main" issue

Comment: Make sure you have `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt`: gunicorn==19.9.0

Comment: Boom, the gunicorn requirement was it, I guess I missed over that notation in your answer initially, you are the man! One note though, remove your notation of **entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project_portal.wsgi:application** in your answer, it needed to stay **entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project_portal.wsgi** as noted here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime